# Why does () => void return something?

Tags: typescript, void

I know that below does NOT mean the return 'type' is void. What I understood is that voidFunc returns nothing since it is returning 'void'. Why does it return any type?

```
type voidFunc = () => void

const myFunc: voidFunc = () => {
  return 'hello'
}
```

How is it different from writing it as  below?
`type voidFunc = () => any`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Assignability of Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#assignability-of-functions)

**Return type void**

The void return type for functions can produce some unusual, but expected behavior.

Contextual typing with a return type of `void` does **not** force functions to **not** return something. Another way to say this is a contextual function type with a `void` return type (`type vf = () => void`), when implemented, can return any other value, but it will be ignored.

Thus, the following implementations of the type `() => void` are valid:

```ts
type voidFunc = () => void;
 
const f1: voidFunc = () => {
  return true;
};
 
const f2: voidFunc = () => true;
 
const f3: voidFunc = function () {
  return true;
};
```

And when the return value of one of these functions is assigned to another variable, it will retain the type of void:

```ts
const v1 = f1();
 
const v2 = f2();
 
const v3 = f3();
```

Comment: It's so confusing because when you type `let a:void = myFunc()` and then `console.log(a)` it still logs `hello`.... Why bother typing `void` if it isn't enforced...

Comment: @Kokodoko The link above explains why assigning a method returning sth to method returning a void is accepted: to make `src.forEach((el) => dst.push(el));` legal. I also find it confusing - especially when you cast return value to `any`, as you did in `console.log` example.